# Is it possible for function in Osgood criterion to have bounded derivative?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Osgood_criterion, is it possible for the function $\omega$ to have bounded first derivative on some interval starting at 0, $[0,a] $? If so would these be a large subclass of these functions?

Answer (score 1):

If $\omega$ has bounded first derivative on $[0,a]$, i.e. $0\leq \omega'(s) \leq L$ for every $s\in [0,a]$, then $0\leq \omega(s) \leq L s$ for every $s\in [0,a]$ and the condition
$$
|f(x_1, t) - f(x_2, t)| \leq \omega(|x_1-x_2|)\qquad \forall t, x_1, x_2
$$
is essentially the standard condition of the Cauchy-Picard-Lipschitz theorem (i.e., $f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous w.r.t. the $x$ variable, uniformly w.r.t. $t$).

This point is discussed in the Remarks of your link.

Comment: thank you, answers my question completely